# Unexpected result with MIN function in ms-access caused by text field with empty string

Tags: function, ms-access, min

If I use the MIN function on a text field, I get an unexpected result.
I have a table with one text field with following values 'a', '', 'c'.
My expectation is that the empty value is returned (when you would sort the table the empty string comes before the 'a'), but instead I get the 'c' as a result !!!

One should easily be able to see this problem by performing the following queries in an access database:

create table testbug (Field1 varchar (255) NULL)
  insert into testbug (Field1) values ('a')
  insert into testbug (Field1) values ('')
  insert into testbug (Field1) values ('c')
  insert into testbug (Field1) values ('d')
  select min(field1) from testbug

If the blank value contains something else (even a space for example) then it works correct!
Can anyone reproduce this and/or explain and/or indicate whether this is a known bug (I could not find anything about this).

I work with the following version:

Microsoft Office Professional 2010
  Microsoft Access Version: 14.0.7166.5000 (32-bit)

Comment: Does it work correctly if you index `Field1`?

Comment: Yes, it works well with an index added. Nice suggustion! But I don't want to add indexes on fields just to let the MIN function work correctly. I also can't add the index most of the times because I'm mostly working with databases of customers where I can't/may not edit anything, only query.

Answer (score 1):

MIN simply ignores NULL values.

If you still want to use MIN with NULL values you can try :

```
SELECT MIN(Nz(Field1, " ")) FROM testbug
```

Comment: First there is no NULL value in my table, only an empty string. If the MIN function ignores empty strings by design I would expect this to see on following page, but I don't: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Min-Max-Functions-6636b171-56b9-434d-adfd-e1b2a5317b58 

Still if it is true what you say, why does it return 'c' and not 'a'?

Comment: I could only find Transact-SQL definition of MIN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx when MIN is applied to a string, it choses the last character in alphabetical order, here 'c'. Finally, I think that Access-SQL process an empty string like a NULL, but don't quote me on this one.

Comment: Excuse me for m'y last sentence, it's not true.

Answer (score 0):

the MIN function indeed seems to handle empty values (zero length string values) as NULL.
I added a Field2 to your testbug table and added two rows manually:

- no value for Field1, value 'k' for Field2
- value for Field1, value 'l' for Field2, remove value for Field1

I also entered a value 'm' in Field2 for the second row you inserted in your table.
Next, I ran this query:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, 
IIf(min(Field1) Is Null,'null','not null') AS result, Len(Field1)
FROM testbug
GROUP BY Field1, Field2
```

The IIF function returns null for all values being null or empty.
For the second row you inserted, the function Len returns 0, meaning this is a zero length value. However, the IIF function returns null.
Meaning, MIN seems to handle empty values as NULL values.
Apparently, this is standard behavior within MS Access.

Hope this helps.
Also hope help here was better than the help you got on Helpmij ;)

Comment: thanks for the time you took to examine the problem (and especially thanks for the sympathy you have shown about my Helpmij experiences ;-)

It could be that the MIN function of ms-access handles empty values as NULL values and for that reason does not return the emtpy value as a result, but in that case we would expect the 'a' instead of the 'c', wouldn't we?

Comment: Apparently not. If you add this WHERE clause **Len(NZ(Veld1,'')) <> 0** it seems to sort the results just fine. I agree this is non-logical behavior.